# Replace the dash by a slash on WooCommerce product prices range

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, range, price

I would like to replace the dash ( **-** ) by aslash ( **/** ) on WooCommerce product price range.

So the displayed price range must be, for example `$100 / $200` instead of `$100 - $200`

Here is a screenshot of what I mean.

[image: Here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `str_replace()` function in `woocommerce_format_price_range` filter hook, will replace the dash by a slash for WooCommerce product prices range:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_price_range', 'custom_format_price_range', 10, 3 );
function custom_format_price_range( $price ) {
    $price = str_replace('&ndash;', '&#47;', $price);
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.